# Custom Clone button to allow record type selection before redirecting to cloned record edit page

Tags: custom-button, record-type, urlhacking, clone

I have a custom clone button on opportunity which clones an opportunity record along with its record type which is good. However, as part of this clone process we want to facilitate the user with the ability to select a record type(Out of 4 available record types) before landing the user on cloned page. Please let me know the best possible way to achieve this. Below is the existing custom clone button

```
location.replace('{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&00N80000004hYb5=&00N80000004qYbA=&00N340000050hL9=');
```

Comment: What have you thought of doing or tried? Have you looked at a screen flow?

Comment: With the flow I’m having trouble to get to screen with all cloned opp fields to allow user to make any further changes on record before creating

Comment: Is this Classic or Lightning?

Comment: Currently in classic but aiming to facilitate both